# Pandas isin issue with floating numbers

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, ceil

I have two data frame.  df1 (2584x15) and df2(5665x45).
df2 has time columns in msec whereas df1 is in seconds.mseconds. I want to extract all rows of df2 which matches with time instant of df1.

Comment: Is possible identify which values not match?

Comment: Or what are floats which not matched?

Comment: I think for identify `df = df2.loc[df2['Time(msec)'].isin(df1['Time(s)'].mul(1000)), 'Time(msec)']` should works

Comment: Sorry, I dont explain it nice. I think if is possible get data which cannot match, but you think it should match.

Comment: @Jezrael.I am trying to attach the raw data but again it is taking lot of time to format these data. Do not know exactly how to attach atleast two columns of data .

Comment: What about use [`usecols`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#filtering-columns-usecols) ?

Comment: Maybe you should try to round (truncate) the data just in case there is some decimals issues.

Comment: @ Jezrael. How to attach raw data :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely due to rounding errors from floating point arithmetic. Cast to integer, and you should be fine:

```
df = df2[df2['Time(msec)'].astype(int).isin(df1['Time(s)'].mul(1000).astype(int))]
```

Comment: @ Ken Wei. No I got the same result as before.[2398 rows x 31 columns]. I will try to attach the raw data.